# How to recover the struct from a Document in Golang package, Bleve

Tags: go, search, bleve

It would be most convenient if I was able to get back the indexed struct from my [Bleve](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/blevesearch/bleve@v1.0.14) `SearchResults`. This is what I know and what I have:
I have `SearchResults.Hits` which I can iterate over, and get the Document with `index.Document(hit.ID)`. With the document, I also have access to its fields. What I could do is manually reconstruct the struct. However, in another question about Bleve on here it was mentioned that one can use `index.GetInternal(hit.ID)` to get back the original struct, if Index Internal has been set. There is `index.SetInternal(key, val []byte) error`, but I am very much at a loss for how to use this accomplish what I wish to. I dug in to the code, but it honestly didn't offer my limited knowledge any insight. How could I set it up so that I only need to invoke `index.GetInternal` to retrieve a struct from my search results?

Answer (score 0):

Marty Schoch [does not recommend that solution anymore](https://github.com/blevesearch/bleve/issues/174#issuecomment-659645898).

What he suggested instead is:

- encode your struct:

```go
    doc := document.Document{
        ID: post.URI,
    }
    if err := bleve.NewIndexMapping().MapDocument(&doc, post); err != nil {
        return errors.Errorf("failed to map document: %v", err)
    }

    var b bytes.Buffer
    enc := gob.NewEncoder(&b)
    if err := enc.Encode(post); err != nil {
        return errors.Errorf("failed to encode post: %v", err)
    }
```

- add a new field to store encoded bytes:

```go
    field := document.NewTextFieldWithIndexingOptions("_source", nil, b.Bytes(), document.StoreField)
    if err := batch.IndexAdvanced(doc.AddField(field)); err != nil {
        return errors.Errorf("failed to add index to the batch: %v", err)
    }
```

- decode the search results:

```go
    query := bleve.NewMatchQuery(value)
    request := bleve.NewSearchRequest(query)
    request.Fields = []string{"_source"}
    searchResults, err := ps.index.Search(request)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.Errorf("failed to execute a search request: %v", err)
    }

    var searchPosts []*blog.Post
    for _, result := range searchResults.Hits {
        var post *blog.Post
        b := bytes.NewBuffer([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("%v", result.Fields["_source"])))
        dec := gob.NewDecoder(b)
        if err = dec.Decode(&post); err != nil {
            return nil, errors.Errorf("failed to decode post: %v", err)
        }
        searchPosts = append(searchPosts, post)
    }
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/michaeljs1990/25f9949c10ab64d971422dda44feea0e